# Создание объекта модели Django

Tags: python, django

Проблема в создании объекта модели.

Есть модели Book, Author, Genre, Language.

Поля Book:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=13, help_text='13 символов <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN номера</a> книги')
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Выберите жанр книги')
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language', max_length=20, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Создаю объект:

```
Book.objects.create(title='Заводной Апельсин', author=Author('Энтони', 'Берджесс', '1917-02-25', '1993-11-22'), summary='Книга про заводной апельсин и глумную молодежь', isbn='3790173756384', genre=Genre('роман'), language=Language('Русский'))
```

Объект не создается из-за неправильного описания жанра. Получаю ошибку: `Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited.`

Понимаю, что при связи many-to-many жанр должен описываться иначе, чем при foreign key, НО КАК?

Answer (score 1):

```
book = Book.objects.create(title='Заводной Апельсин',
                           author=Author('Энтони', 'Берджесс', '1917-02-25', '1993-11-22'),
                           summary='Книга про заводной апельсин и глумную молодежь',
                           isbn='3790173756384', language=Language('Русский'))

book.genre.add(Genre.objects.get_or_create(name='роман'))
```

Comment: ```TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Genre'````

Comment: А если же не прописывать (name='роман'), а просто написать ('роман'), то выдает вот что:
`catalog.models.Genre.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Genre -- it returned 3!`
Роман только один (нет романа-эпопеи, напривмер)